# Owncloud WebDAV authentication possible via web interface but not desktop client

Tags: apache-http-server, php, webdav, owncloud

I just set up Owncloud on my shared webspace and got everything working except authentication from desktop clients. If I go to the WebDAV Url via my webbrowser it just presents me an empty form again, and the owncloud desktop client says: `Error: Wrong Credentials`

If I visit the WebDAV Url via a browser where I just logged in via the web interface, it shows me the directory (I am not asked for user/password)

My password doesn't contain characters other than a-z,A-Z,0-9

### Log warnings:

```
curl_setopt_array() [<a href='function.curl-setopt-array'>function.curl-setopt-array</a>]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set at /path/to/my/home/cloud/3rdparty/Sabre/DAV/Client.php#462
```

You can try here: http://martinbertschler.com/cloud/ with user pass: `demo demo`

Comment: If all you get is a directory listing via the web clearly something went wrong with the install. Have you been able to access any aspect of it without some form of error?

Comment: the only thing that doesn't work is the documents app, it is not able to load my document to edit it.

Comment: Well, the bug report @MatthewWilliams linked is right on the mark. It also contains a single decisive line – IMHO telling you not to use OwnCloud: "They don't implement it because it's a Junior Job."

Comment: i would really love to use OwnCloud :( but with this restriction it doesn't make sense...

Comment: I give up, after trying it at another webhoster. owncloud is just not made for shared environments. I will try to build myself a sync tool with a php webdav and rsync

Answer (score 1):

According to their GitHub devs  [here](https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/1916), CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION can't be used at all when an open_basedir is set.

They also provide a php workaround  [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#102121), but the idea would be to remove the open_basedir from your php.ini.

I suggest commenting it out. This should deal with the error log you posted then we can see what works and go from there.

Comment: thank you for this answer, but I fear that the host of my webspace would not change that for me :/

Comment: Is this a live website? Might be useful if you provide a link

Comment: yes it is, changed question: You can try here: http://martinbertschler.com/cloud/ with user pass: demo demo

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect your webserver provider has something weird in their php setup. Can you try doing a clean install of your OwnCloud instance? It is interesting you can upload files to the files section, but not documents.